# Swift 2: Value of type 'Set<UITouch>' has no member 'anyObject'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode, uitouch

I checked my old game and I want to update it in Swift 2.0. When I tried to fix it, Xcode found an error. Error is **Value of type 'Set' has no member 'anyObject'** on this line of code:

```
var touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
```

**function:**

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("torpedo.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))

    var touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch //<-- Here is Error
    var location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)

    var torpedo:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "torpedo")
    torpedo.position = player.position

    torpedo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedo.size.width/2)
    torpedo.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    torpedo.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory
    torpedo.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = alienCategory
    torpedo.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    torpedo.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    var offset:CGPoint = vecSub(location, b: torpedo.position)

    if (offset.y < 0){
        return

    self.addChild(torpedo)

    var direction:CGPoint = vecNormalize(offset)

    var shotLength:CGPoint = vecMult(direction, b: 1000)

    var finalDestination:CGPoint = vecAdd(shotLength, b: torpedo.position)

    let velocity = 568/1
    let moveDuration:Float = Float(self.size.width) / Float(velocity)

    var actionArray:NSMutableArray =  NSMutableArray()
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(moveDuration)))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
}
```

So what to fix here ?

Comment: The answers there are not clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given a `Set` of `UITouch` defined as follow

```
touches: Set<UITouch>
```

you can retrieve a touch with this code

```
let touch = touches.first
```

### Generics

There is no need to force cast the retrieved element to `UITouch`. Infact now the Apple APIs written in Objective-C have been updated with generics. This means that in this case you receive a `Set` of `UITouch` (not a `Set` of `NSObject` that could literally contains any object).
So the `Set` **already knows** the contained elements are `UITouch`.

### Optionals

The `first` computed property does return an `Optional`. Infact if the `Set` is empty it does return `nil`.

A good and safe technique to unwrap the element is

```
guard let touch = touches.first else {
    debugPrint("Ops, no touch found...")
    return
}

// here you can use touch
```

Comment: Ya, It's working. Thanks sir :)

Comment: Great, good luck with your game!

Comment: I'm ready to help but you should create a new question.

Comment: Here is other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374830/swift-2-cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutablearray-to-expected-argument-type