# Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[SKAction]'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsmutablearray, swift2, skaction

I checked my old game (made in SpriteKit) and I want to update it in Swift 2.0. When I tried to fix it, Xcode found an errors.

Error is: **Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[SKAction]'**

In code:

```
torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

**Function:**

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("torpedo.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))

var touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch 
var location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)

var torpedo:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "torpedo")
torpedo.position = player.position

torpedo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedo.size.width/2)
torpedo.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
torpedo.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory
torpedo.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = alienCategory
torpedo.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
torpedo.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

var offset:CGPoint = vecSub(location, b: torpedo.position)

if (offset.y < 0){
    return

self.addChild(torpedo)

var direction:CGPoint = vecNormalize(offset)

var shotLength:CGPoint = vecMult(direction, b: 1000)

var finalDestination:CGPoint = vecAdd(shotLength, b: torpedo.position)

let velocity = 568/1
let moveDuration:Float = Float(self.size.width) / Float(velocity)

var actionArray:NSMutableArray =  NSMutableArray()
actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(moveDuration)))
actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray)) //<-- Here is Error
```

}

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

To run a sequence of actions use this code

```
// REMOVE THIS var actionArray:NSMutableArray =  NSMutableArray()
let move = SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(moveDuration))
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move,remove]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead:

```
var actionArray = Array<SKAction>()
actionArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(moveDuration)))
actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

The method expects a parameter of type [SKAction] which NSMutableArray does not conform to.